# Recognise given timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp, timezone

The converted time is: 2016/06/21 02:14:33
The timestamp without conversion: 2346273

Timestamp without conversion is returned by an API response but not able to understand which timestamp conversion is used to get 2016/06/21 02:14:33 Human readable format.

Comment: Which API returns this value?  Does it have documentation?  Can you give additional examples?  How are you determining how the values are correlated?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, APIs for LISK Coin is returning these values. https://lisk.io/documentation/lisk-core/api#/Transactions/getTransactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments:

> APIs for LISK Coin is returning these values.

That helps. Though it's not clear in LISK's documentation, a bit of searching found [this post on Reddit's LISK forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lisk/comments/7qkzcm/question_regarding_timestamp_in_lisk/dspz6mu/), which says:

> Timestamps in lisk are the number of seconds since the creation of the Lisk genesis block. The Lisk genesis block was created on May 24th, 2016.

It then goes on to show a genesis date of precisely `2016-05-24T17:00:00.000Z`  (UTC).

Thus, we can do this:

```
var dt = new Date("2016-05-24T17:00:00.000Z");  // start with the LISK genesis date
dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + (2346273 * 1000));    // add your timestamp * 1000 (seconds to ms)
```

You now have a `Date` object correctly representing this point in time.  If you call `.toString()` on it, it will use the computer's local time zone to produce the output string.

For me, here in the US Pacific time zone:

```
dt.toString()
// "Mon Jun 20 2016 13:44:33 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
```

If I change my time zone to India, then I'll get the date and time you provided:

```
dt.toString()
// "Tue Jun 21 2016 02:14:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

I could also get this without changing my system time zone, and in a more compact format, by directly providing the locale code and time zone ID for India:

```
dt.toLocaleString('en-IN', {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'})
// "21/6/2016, 2:14:33 am"
```

Or if you want the exact UTC timestamp in ISO 8601 format, then

```
dt.toISOString()
// "2016-06-20T20:44:33.000Z"
```

One other thing to note - this genesis timestamp is not mentioned in the docs you linked to.  In those docs, it say says this value is a regular Unix Timestamp.  Unix timestamps are based on `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`, not on `2016-05-24T17:00:00.000Z`.  So either their docs are wrong, or they're referring to something newer than what you are using.

Comment: That extra information sure helps :p Somehow I knew the OP's local timezone was going to be India!!